# What is wrong in the PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blank page in my site. So I checked error logs and found:

[15-Nov-2013 05:43:29] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/techmest/public_html/wp-config.php on line 59

My wp-config.php contents are http://pastebin.com/p13VtZ4D

Please help.

Comment: And *this* is why you use an IDE with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Even Pastebin show you that there's something wrong with the highlighting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 50, `define ('WPLANG', ');` should be `define ('WPLANG', '');` - missing apostrophe

Comment: Yeah i know and I tried. but still blank page..

Comment: Is it still showing the error?

Comment: Yes a blank page. By the way syntax error is on line 59

Comment: Have you tried to copy a fresh default wp-config.php over and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Woo! that solved. thx for d idea :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is bad:

```
define ('WPLANG', '); // line 50
```

You're missing a value and `'`.

Comment: Yeah i know and I tried. but still blank page..

Answer (score 0):

In line 50,

```
define ('WPLANG', ');
```

is the error. Single Quote isn't closed